# How do I add() ArrayList to a 2D ArrayList without overwriting prior entries?

Tags: java, android, arrays, 2d, overwrite

Okay, so I know why this is happening: cv.add(curid, temp); is adding a reference to temp, temp's content changes later, resulting in all the entries being the same because they're all linked to temp. I looked up solutions but I can't get one that applies to my situation, see below:

```
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
         Context context = getApplicationContext();
         Resources res = context.getResources();
         XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.thedata);
         ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cv = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

         //Helper stuff
         int curid = 0;
         ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                 if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                     curid = Integer.parseInt(xpp.nextText());
                 } 
                 if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("data") == false){
                     temp.add(xpp.getName() + "<>" + xpp.nextText());
                 }

             } 
             else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room")){
                 cv.add(curid, temp);
                 temp.clear();
             }
             eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
             //Restart Loop
         }
```

I need to populate the ArrayList temp in the loop first, which has made the solutions I've found inapplicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use `Map`. `Map` is a data structure that contains keys and values, first element is key and the second is value :

```
 Map<key,value> myMap = new HashMap<key,value>();
```

so you can easily find the value by just knowing the key of them. in this data structure you do not waste memory, but in arraylist of your example if curid is 2, and the next one is 10, you must put null in all of arraylist indexes of 3,4,5,6,7,8,9. and this makes you track them and reference them difficult.(i assume this , because i think you want for example call something like cv[curId][0], and you must be sure at index [curId] you have a value and it is not null, that makes possibility of creating error very much) so lets try to solve your problem by this new one:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
         Context context = getApplicationContext();
         Resources res = context.getResources();
         XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.thedata);
         Map<int,ArrayList<string>> cv = new HashMap<int,ArrayList<string>>();

         //Helper stuff
         int curid = 0;
         ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                 if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                     curid = Integer.parseInt(xpp.nextText());
                 } 
                 if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("data") == false){
                     temp.add(xpp.getName() + "<>" + xpp.nextText());
                 }

             } 
             else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room")){
                 cv.put(curid,temp);
                 temp = new ArrayList<String>();
             }
             eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
             //Restart Loop
         }
```

now for example you want to access ArrayList of curId = 10

```
ArrayList<String> element = (ArrayList<String>) cv.get(10);
```

for more example look at:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not move all that "Helper stuff" into a helper method?

```
public ArrayList<String> helperMethod(XmlResourceParser xpp, MutableInt id) {
     int curid = 0;
     ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
             if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                 curid = Integer.parseInt(xpp.nextText());
             } 
             if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id") == false && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("data") == false){
                 temp.add(xpp.getName() + "<>" + xpp.nextText());
             }

         } 
         else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("room")){
             id.setValue(curid);
             break;
         }
         eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
         //Restart Loop
     }
     return temp;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
ArrayList<String> tempList;
MutableInt id = new MutableInt(0);
while((tempList = helperMethod(xpp, id)) != null) {
    cv.add(id, tempList);
}
```